# Amount of rows in sheet

Tags: excel, vba

Goal:
A variable should contain amount of rows from a specific sheet.

Problem:
What syntax code in Excel VBA do I need to count amount of rows from sheet?

Comment: If you mean total rows, `Worksheet.Rows.Count` will do it.  If you mean something else, let us know.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Using the usedrange method is one of my favourites but it needs to be treated with care.  It has a few flaws/gotchas.  It is a known problem that excel does not keep track of the used range very well. Any reference to the used range via VBA will reset the value to the current used range. So try running this sub procedure when you are getting the used range:

```
Dim lRowCount as Long

Application.ActiveSheet.UsedRange
lRowCount = Worksheets("MySheet").UsedRange.Rows.Count
```

But be aware this will give you the **used** range count, so if you have blank rows at the top of your workbook (which often people do to leave space for things like filter criteria etc) then they will not be counted. The usedrange method can also be affected by formatting.

If you want the last row used, which is what I think you want, then you can use the find method which is more reliable:

```
Dim rLastCell As Range
Dim lLastRow  As Long

Set rLastCell = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False)

If Not rLastCell Is Nothing Then lLastRow = rLastCell.Row
```

If you know that you have atleast one cell with data in it, then you can simplify the above to:

```
Dim lLastRow  As Long

lLastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False).Row
```

[See here regarding used range I spoke about above](http://www.j-walk.com/ss/excel/tips/tip73.htm)

Answer (score 14):

You can also try:

```
i = Sheets("SheetName").UsedRange.Rows.Count
```

However, this can get a little buggy if you start deleting and clearing rows.

A better way to do this is:

```
i = Cells(Sheets("SheetName").Rows.Count, 1).End(xlup).Row
```

This assumes that each row has data in column 1.