# Extract Multiple Rows into a Limited Template based on Multiple Criterias

Tags: excel, database, vba, extract

I have an issue in extracting from "Datadump" into several continuous "Template" (as the template can only contain 10 rows of item).

Here are my intentions:

1. From the data dump (sample above), is it possible to automatically extract the appropriate value into the Template with a maximum of 10 rows for each set of Template. And then colour-code those that have been printed to the Template.
   !-[Template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rdIQD.png)]
   These are the Template (Payment Voucher) limitations:

   a. Each template contains the data from only **1 (one) day**

If in 1st January 2020 & 2nd January 2020, there are 5 transactions **/day**, there would have to be **2 Templates (1 for each day).**

b. Each Template should only be from **1 Source**

So if in 1st January 2020 & 2nd January 2020, there are 5 transactions/day from **each Source A & B**, there would be **4 Templates (1 for each source/day)**.

c. Each template could only contain **10 lines.**

So if in 1st January 2020 & 2nd January 2020, there are **11** transactions/day from each Source A & B, there would be **8 Templates (2 for each source/day)**.

I have also attached a Before and After for reference :)

**Before:**

!-[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HoSgk.png)]

!-[Template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rdIQD.png)]

**After:**

!-[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aa3ws.png)]

!-[Voucher Page 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYjYR.png)]

!-[Voucher Page 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RwPQD.png)]

Since I am new to VBA, I would have no issue with the inputs to their appropriate places and to colour code. But I am still learning about the loop function that I believe would be required for this?

Any help would be much appreciated!

@Edit:

Values for the templates are:

```
1. Credit Source = Source + Source Name
2. Total = All values inside the voucher
3. Account = Item Code
4. Detail = Item Name
5. Unit Code = Unit Code
6. Value = Total Debit
```

Here are the codes that I could come up with for now (Trying to break the process down)

@edit @edit

```
Sub learn()
Set wb = ThisWorkbook

Set dtws = Worksheets("Database")
Set wstr = Worksheets("trial")
Dim vcdate
vcdate = wstr.Cells(2, "B").Value
Dim vcsource
vcsource = wstr.Cells(2, "D").Value

Dim NoE As Long
Dim lmtcount As Long

'Limiting No. Of Entries

'With wstr
 '   .Cells(2, 1).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(dtws.Range("A:A"), vcdate, dtws.Range("J:J"), vcsource)

 '   NoE = wstr.Cells(2, 1).Value

'If NoE < 11 Then
'    .Cells(2, 3).Value = NoE
'Else
'    .Cells(2, 3).Value = 10

'End If
'End With

'lmtcount = wstr.Cells(2, 3).Value

'MsgBox NoE
'End of Limiting No. Of Entries


'------------------------
'Inputting Appropriately
'------------------------

Set tempws = Worksheets("Template")

Dim lrow As Long
Dim Count1 As Long

For Count1 = 1 To 100
    lrow = tempws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    'MsgBox lrow
    If lrow = 19 Then Exit For
    '-----------------------------------------
    'MsgBox dtws.Cells(Count1 + 1, "A").Value
    '-----------------------------------------
    'Cross-Check if the same date
    If CDate(dtws.Cells(Count1 + 1, "A").Value) > CDate(vcdate) Then Exit For
    '-----------------------------------------
    'Cross check error
    'MsgBox dtws.Cells(Count1 + 1, "A").Value
    'MsgBox dtws.Cells(Count1 + 1, "J").Value
    '-----------------------------------------
    If dtws.Cells(Count1 + 1, "J").Value2 = vcsource Then
        With tempws
            .Cells(lrow + 1, "A") = dtws.Cells(Count1 + 1, 2)
            .Cells(lrow + 1, "C") = dtws.Cells(Count1 + 1, 3) & " - " & dtws.Cells(Count1 + 1, 5)
            .Cells(lrow + 1, "G") = dtws.Cells(Count1 + 1, 6)
            .Cells(lrow + 1, "I") = dtws.Cells(Count1 + 1, 9)
        End With
       '-----------------------------------------
       'Colour Code
       '-----------------------------------------
       With dtws
            .Cells(Count1 + 1, 2).Interior.Color = 13998939
            .Cells(Count1 + 1, 3).Interior.Color = 13998939
            .Cells(Count1 + 1, 6).Interior.Color = 13998939
            .Cells(Count1 + 1, 9).Interior.Color = 13998939
        End With


    End If


Next Count1


With tempws
        .Cells(20, "I").Formula = "=sum(I10:I19)"
        .Cells(7, "C").Value = tempws.Cells(20, "I").Value
        .Cells(4, "J").Value = vcdate
        .Cells(6, "C").Value = vcsource

End With

'----------------------------------------
'Input Tracking Order
'----------------------------------------
lrowtr = wstr.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
With wstr
    .Cells(lrowtr + 1, "A").Value = vcsource
    .Cells(lrowtr + 1, "B").Value = vcdate
    .Cells(lrowtr + 1, "C").Value = Count1
End With
'----------------------------------------
'End of Input Tracking order
'----------------------------------------

End Sub
```

I believe I would not have an issue with the colour coding but it seems that the data extraction is the main issue...

Any help would be appreciated!

@edit edit edit:
Unfortunately could not make the image appears as it requires at least 10 reps. But if you try to see from the image example, I think it would provide much clarification.

Comment: Hi Albert, welcome to Stackoverflow. `I understand that this might be a long process, So I thought we can take it solve the intentions one by one and I would keep on editing the post` This however won't work, please re-check your code and check what is the specific line that causes your problem. Then we start from there.

Comment: Hi L42,
The thing is that I was hoping that I could get directions from here because I am still learning VBA.
I have also checked several forums and posts but found no post about extracting the data into several continuous template.
So if it helps, please disregard my attempt in the code as I was still building it up since I found that stitching codes from other posts didnt help me in this one particular case....

Answer (score 0):

An example for multi criteria matching is in [Multiple Criteria Match/Index VBA Across two sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59615083/multiple-criteria-match-index-vba-across-two-sheets)

The multi criteria matching is in the lines

```
If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(s, 1).Value = ID And ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(s, 2).Value = Activity Then
                ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(s, 3).Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(r, 3).Value
            End If
```

where the `And` connects the multiple criteria, in this case 2 criteria. `And` is the logical AND function, in excel are available 3 other logical operators OR, XOR and NOT ( https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2014/12/17/excel-and-or-xor-not-functions/ ) that can also be used for multi criteria matching. The main structure for comparing and matching is `If`

In the code are used two **nested** loops, one loops through row 1 and 3 of *sheet1* the other loops through row 1 and 3 of *sheet2*, in the 'core' of these two nested loopes the comparing, matching is performed. So if you want to loop through 2 rows of two sheets use the following :

```
For r = 2 To ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count

          ... 

        For s = 2 To ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").UsedRange.Rows.Count

           ...

        Next s
    Next r
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer!

Thank you for the example of the For loop.

Would you mind helping in extracting the extracted information that fits those criterias into several continuous templates? (As each template could only hold 10 lines)?

Would truly appreciate it!

Comment: i do not understand what criterias have to be matched because when looking at the datadump you can extract simply the columns, i.e. `source code` is column 8 and `source name` is column 9 . To count the maximal values i would use a counter like `Dim count1 as Integer` then count up with ` count1 = count1+1` if you insert an item into the template see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26619200/creating-a-counter-in-vba, possibly you need many counters, one for each item (or column) in the template . After counting up compare with `If ... End If` statement if 10 entries are exceeded yet

Comment: And if you want to grab the top 10 entries of a column or category you can follow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34516441/vba-extract-top-x-entries-from-each-category or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19546388/vba-excel-extract-data-from-column-c-and-place-into-column-d

Comment: For appending `source name` to `source code` after you copied `source code` to the template using vba or a formula, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32054665/how-do-i-concatenate-cell-values-and-text-together-using-excel-vba

Comment: Whoa! thank you very much for all these resources!
To answer the criterias to be matched, these are the Template (Payment Voucher) limitations:

1. Each template should only be from 1 Source
2. Each template contains the data from only **1 (one) day**
3. Each template could only contain 10 lines.

Thank you very much for the inputs! I have edited the post for further clarifications based from your inputs!

Comment: Hey Ralf, is there any possibilities that you can help with the code for the Template limitations?

Comment: The problem is that i do not know exactly how you want to implement the limitation. For example you can protect the sheet after entry of 10 rows (  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DlSl5Je-4HE - How to lock cells after entry is made in Excel)

Comment: Another way is hiding unused cells and then protect the sheet or limit the scroll area, this is all explained in https://www.lifewire.com/limit-rows-and-columns-in-excel-4178646 and https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2649-excel-limit-number-of-rows-columns.html and can also be done using vba

Comment: Hi Ralf,

I think we have a different focus here.
So let's take a step back.

What I really need help the most is that if let's say if there are **15 entries** that fit the criteria, How can I automatically paste them into a continuous Template (Page 1 & 2)?

Comment: There are multiple ways to do this: You can check if your template is empty and write 10 entries if yes or you check how many rows in your template are occupied, lets say x, and write 10-x entries until the first sheet/page is full (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11595816/amount-of-rows-in-sheet). Then you create a new sheet in your template workbook and repeat the procedure (check if empty of how many rows are free) and write the remaining entries

Comment: Hey Ralf, as I can see from the link that you provided and that you provided before. Are you referring for me to do the last part manually? (Inputting page X of Y on top right hand corner, creating new template format and running the code again?)

Comment: i think this depends on how long you want to store the templates in excel. If you can reuse them or transfer the information to a database immediately you do not have to create new ones and overwrite the old. And you can create new sheets in a workbook by code

Comment: I would love to be able to store the templates for now. and since there would be a lot. Maybe 20 templates / sheet? I thought of using lastrow with added space between templates and I think it works fine. But still struggling with VBA identifying whether it is continuation and add the details accordingly.

Comment: Forthe continuation problem you can use the `DAY` function https://analystcave.com/vba-reference-functions/vba-date-functions/vba-day-function/ because you have a date Then write anything from same day and same source to one template, for this you have to filter the datadump for date and source using loops and IF ... THEN like in https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/loop-through-entire-column.html for two columns code is in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59615083/multiple-criteria-match-index-vba-across-two-sheets (multiple criteria match)

Comment: Instead of loops you can also use `VLOOKUP` https://exceljet.net/formula/vlookup-by-date

Answer (score 0):

Herllo albertd,

Just in case you may have missed it, I posted a fairly thorough answer for you here last week.

http://www.excelfox.com/forum/showthread.php/2402-Extract-Multiple-Rows-into-a-Limited-Template-based-on-Multiple-Criterias?p=11847#post11847
http://www.excelfox.com/forum/showthread.php/2345-Appendix-Thread-(-Codes-for-other-Threads-HTML-Tables-etc-)?p=11846&viewfull=1#post11846

A few minor things might be missing, but having read through the comments here, I expect you can do some minor mods to get things like the formatting.

I would have just put this in a comment, but I can only comment on my own questions. So to satisfy the forum etiquette, I will post my macro solution. The details can be seen at that excelfox link.

```
    Option Explicit
    Sub DoItForADay()
    Rem 1 Worksheets info
    Dim WsTp As Worksheet, WsDta As Worksheet, WsSmry As Worksheet
     Set WsTp = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Template"): Set WsDta = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Datadump"): Set WsSmry = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary")
    Rem 2 The days and source list
    ' 2a) Put all info in an array
    Dim LrDta As Long: Let LrDta = WsDta.Range("A" & WsDta.Rows.Count & "").End(xlUp).Row
    Dim arrAllDts() As Variant           '  In the naxt line, the  .Value  Property ( method ) , is used to return in one go all  Values  in the range.  They are returned as a field, ( array ) of values in  held in  Variant  type  elements.  So we must use Variant for the  Dim ing  of the type of our Elements, or else the next code line will error , with a  Mismatch error
     Let arrAllDts = WsDta.Range("A4:M" & LrDta & "").Value '  I am adding  column M  for my own amusement
    ' 2b)

    ' 2c) make an array with all unique identifier for each voucher
    Dim Cnt As Long
        For Cnt = 1 To UBound(arrAllDts(), 1) ' Looping effectively from forth row until last row in  Datadump
    Dim Idt As String
         Let Idt = arrAllDts(Cnt, 1) & "_" & arrAllDts(Cnt, 8) & " - " & arrAllDts(Cnt, 9) '  I am adding a  "_"  to in between the   date   and   source info  : Later I can split the   unique identifiers  string by this  "_"  in order to get the date and souce info
         Let arrAllDts(Cnt, 13) = Idt
        Dim strDtsSrc As String
            If InStr(1, strDtsSrc, Idt, vbBinaryCompare) = 0 Then
             Let strDtsSrc = strDtsSrc & Idt & "###"
            Else
            ' case we already have the date in our string,  strDts
            End If
        Next Cnt
     Let strDtsSrc = Left(strDtsSrc, (Len(strDtsSrc) - 3)) '  take off the last space  "###"  which we do not need
     'Debug.Print strDtsSrc
    ' 2d)
    Dim arrUnicDtsSrc() As String
     Let arrUnicDtsSrc() = Split(strDtsSrc, "###", -1)
     Let Worksheets("arrUnicDtsSrc").Range("A1").Resize(1, (UBound(arrUnicDtsSrc()) + 1)).Value = arrUnicDtsSrc()      '    arrUnicDtsSrc().jpg  --- https://imgur.com/QX1bJMB
     Worksheets("arrUnicDtsSrc").Columns.AutoFit
     Let Worksheets("arrAllDts").Range("A4:M" & LrDta & "").Value = arrAllDts()
     ' The next code line can be removed to get all the 19 worksheets
     ReDim arrUnicDtsSrc(0 To 0): Let arrUnicDtsSrc(0) = "01.01.2020_99909900 - A" ' ***** I am limiting it to the first unique identifier, ( 01.01.2020_99909900 - A ) just for demo purposes. If you remove this line,  then you will see that all dates and sources  will be considered
    Rem 3                               ' === Main Outer loop ============================================================
    Dim Stear As Variant    '   For Each  unique identifier  . In VBA,
        For Each Stear In arrUnicDtsSrc() ' Doing stuff For Each  unique identifier
        '3a) work out how many rows and which row indicies with the current unique identifier
        Dim DteSrcRwCnt As Long
            For Cnt = 1 To UBound(arrAllDts(), 1) ' ----------------------Going through all data rows
             If arrAllDts(Cnt, 13) = CStr(Stear) Then ' I am looking for rows in the main datadump that have the current unique identifier
            '3a)(i) counting rows
                                                                               ' Debug.Print Cnt + 3 & " " & arrAllDts(Cnt, 13)
              Let DteSrcRwCnt = DteSrcRwCnt + 1  '  counting the rows for the current unique identifier
             '3a)(ii) get the (row) indicies for the current unique identifier. Later i need the row number of all the rows corresponding to the current unique identifier
             Dim strRws As String
              Let strRws = strRws & Cnt + 3 & " " ' I later wont the actual row in the datadump worksheet, so that is 3 higher than the "row" number in  arrAllDts()  because I captured just the range from the 4th row  --    "A4:M........
             Else
             End If
            Next Cnt                              ' ----------------------Going through all data rows
         Let strRws = Left(strRws, (Len(strRws) - 1))   ' Take of last  " "  which I do not need
        Dim arrRws() As String ' The VBA string function returns field of string type elements. So I must Dim my array elements appropriately
         Let arrRws() = Split(strRws, " ", -1, vbBinaryCompare) ' This gives us an array which is the row numbers  in the  Datadump  for this unique identifier
         Let ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("arrRws").Range("A1").Resize(1, (UBound(arrRws()) + 1)).Value = arrRws() '   arrRws().JPG - https://imgur.com/HDgpyQq                          -
         ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("arrRws").Columns.AutoFit
        '3b) In the  "Magic Code line"  below we need a  "vertical" array     https://www.excelforum.com/excel-new-users-basics/1099995-application-index-with-look-up-rows-and-columns-arguments-as-vba-arrays.html#post4571172
        Dim arrRwsT() As Long
         ReDim arrRwsT(1 To UBound(arrRws()) + 1, 1 To 1) ' a  "Vertical"  1 column array
            For Cnt = 1 To UBound(arrRws()) + 1
             Let arrRwsT(Cnt, 1) = arrRws(Cnt - 1)
            Next Cnt
        Let ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("arrRwsT").Range("A1:A" & UBound(arrRws()) + 1 & "").Value = arrRwsT()  '                             -         arrRwsT().JPG - https://imgur.com/syf0PaZ
        Rem 4 Make Vouchers for current unique identifier, Stear
        ' 4a)
        Dim arrVouch() As Variant    '     https://www.excelforum.com/excel-new-users-basics/1099995-application-index-with-look-up-rows-and-columns-arguments-as-vba-arrays.html#post4571172
         Let arrVouch() = WsTp.Range("A1:K24").Value
        ' 4b) An array just containing the rows for the current Idt
        Dim Clms() As Variant: Let Clms() = Evaluate("=Column(A:N)")    '   {1, 2, 3, 4......14} -   Clms().jpg  -  https://imgur.com/xHlUeH9
        Dim arrDtsSrc() As Variant  '    For   "Magic Code line"     https://www.excelforum.com/excel-new-users-basics/1099995-application-index-with-look-up-rows-and-columns-arguments-as-vba-arrays.html#post4571172
         Let arrDtsSrc() = Application.Index(WsDta.Cells, arrRwsT(), Clms())  ' - --"Magic Code line"      -  arrDtsSrc().JPG : https://imgur.com/0c8SgIn
         Let ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("arrDtsSrc").Range("A1").Resize(UBound(arrDtsSrc(), 1), UBound(arrDtsSrc(), 2)).Value = arrDtsSrc() '                             -         arrRwsT().JPG - https://imgur.com/syf0PaZ
        Dim RwCnt As Long: Let RwCnt = 1: Let Cnt = 1
        ' 4c)
            Do While RwCnt < DteSrcRwCnt + 1 ' ............................................
                Do While Cnt < 11 ' _________________________________|
                 '   Fill in values in Voucher Array
                 Let arrVouch(Cnt + 9, 1) = "'" & arrDtsSrc(RwCnt, 2)   '  The extra   "'"   is one way to keep the leading 0s
                 Let arrVouch(Cnt + 9, 4) = arrDtsSrc(RwCnt, 3)    '   Detail  ( Item )
                 Let arrVouch(Cnt + 9, 7) = arrDtsSrc(RwCnt, 4)    '   Unit Code
                 Let arrVouch(Cnt + 9, 9) = arrDtsSrc(RwCnt, 11)    '   Value
                 Let Cnt = Cnt + 1
                 Let RwCnt = RwCnt + 1
                Loop ' While Cnt < 11 ' ______________________________|
             Let arrVouch(6, 3) = Split(Stear, "_", 2, vbBinaryCompare)(1) ' The second array element (1) is  source code & source name  ( The first array element (0) is the date )
             Let arrVouch(4, 10) = Split(Stear, "_", 2, vbBinaryCompare)(0) ' The first array element (0) is the date
             Let Cnt = 1                       ' back to first row for a template
         '4d) Information to the summary sheet.
            Dim NxtVch As Long: Let NxtVch = WsSmry.Range("A" & WsSmry.Rows.Count & "").End(xlUp).Row
             Let WsSmry.Range("A" & NxtVch + 1 & "").Value = "V" & Format(NxtVch, "0000")
             Let WsSmry.Range("B" & NxtVch + 1 & "").Value = Split(Stear, "_", 2, vbBinaryCompare)(0)
             WsSmry.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=WsSmry.Range("C" & NxtVch + 1 & ""), Address:="", SubAddress:="V" & Format(NxtVch, "0000") & "!A1", TextToDisplay:="Go To Sheet"
         '4e)  Add next voucher
             WsTp.Copy After:=WsDta
             Let ActiveSheet.Name = "V" & Format(NxtVch, "0000")
             Let ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("arrVouch").Range("A1").Resize(UBound(arrVouch(), 1), UBound(arrVouch(), 2)).Value = arrVouch() '                             -         arrRwsT().JPG - https://imgur.com/syf0PaZ
             Let ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(arrVouch(), 1), UBound(arrVouch(), 2)).Value = arrVouch()
             Let arrVouch() = WsTp.Range("A1:K24").Value  ' get a new template array

            Loop ' While RwCnt < DteSrcRwCnt ' .............................................

         Let DteSrcRwCnt = 0 ' ready for next Idt Stear
        Next Stear         ' === Main Outer loop =========================================================================

    End Sub
```

( Your other cross posts, don’t have any answers, and i doubt they will get any, but just for completeness I will add the links..

http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?66589-Extract-Multiple-Rows-into-a-Limited-Template-based-on-Multiple-Criterias
https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/excel-forum/vba-macros/extract-multiple-rows-into-a-limited-template-based-on-multiple-criterias
https://chandoo.org/forum/threads/extract-multiple-rows-into-a-limited-template-based-on-multiple-criterias.43376/
https://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/1301817-extract-multiple-rows-into-a-limited-template-based-on-multiple-criterias.html
https://superuser.com/questions/1515592/extract-multiple-rows-into-a-limited-template-based-on-multiple-criterias

Alan